# modelsummary関数で数値を右に並べたい

Tags: r, rstudio

標準誤差を推定値の下ではなく、右に表示させたいです。
画像では推定値の下に標準誤差が出力されています。

**試したコード:** rstudioで実行し、バージョンはR version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)になります。

```
library(modelsummary)
model_summary <- modelsummary(model, output = "default", statistic = "std.error")
```

**現状の結果:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[modelsummary のマニュアル](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modelsummary/modelsummary.pdf) の 50 〜 51ページ（Examples ->  # estimate）を参考にした記述例を下記に示します。

```
library(modelsummary)

model <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp, mtcars)
model_summary <- modelsummary(model,
                              statistic = NULL,
                              estimate = "{estimate} ({std.error})")
model_summary
```

[image: 出力結果]

Comment: こちらの回答の方が私の回答よりも簡潔なコードになります。有意水準のスターを入れたい方は、こちらのコードに、`stars = TRUE`を付け加え、`estimate = "{estimate}{stars}({std.error})"`のようにすればできます。estimateの中の順番も自由に変えることができました。